# Why my django project url direct old one when I use pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

first of all, i use pycharm to create a django project **pj2**, obviously, I already have one **pj1** before this.

**pj1** was created in virtualenv called **venv**. when I run new project

```
cd pj2
python manage.py runserver
```

it will enter the url **127.0.0.1:8000/catalog**, whether or not i create **pj2** in virtual environment. **catalog** is **pj1**'s app.

why did that happen?  its ok in cmd. so i think the problem is pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the correct virtual environment is selected, go to:

```
Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter
```

Also verify your Django project root, Settings, and Manage script are correct:

```
Preferences -> Languages & Framework -> Django
```

Comment: thats weird, I delete the **venv** folder, even the whole **pj1** project, the it is still  **127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/**. weird...